# custom collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

[EDIT: I have added a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls40d.png)

I have used Custom Collection View Cell. The problem is when I scroll the list fast horizontally I get 2 images in my Image View in some cells.
Please help me understand why its happening and how can I rectify it?

This is collection view code-

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  //  static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"cell3";
    MostPopularViewCell *cell3 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



         cell3.clipsToBounds=YES;
            cell3.mostproductprice.text=[[mostPopularArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
            cell3.mostproductnm.text=[[mostPopularArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"pirce"];


            NSDictionary *Scrapdict=[mostPopularArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                     NSString *img_str=[Scrapdict objectForKey:@"small_image"];
            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:img_str];
            AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell3.mostProductimg.bounds];
            imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;


            [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:imageView];
            //set image URL. AsyncImageView class will then dynamically load the image
            ((AsyncImageView *)imageView).imageURL =url;


          //  imageView.clipsToBounds=YES;
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            cell3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            cell3.mostProductimg.image=nil;

                   //imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
            imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            //cell3.mostProductimg.clipsToBounds=YES;

            [cell3.mostProductimg  addSubview:imageView];
            cell3.mostProductimg.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [AsyncImageLoader defaultCache];

            [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader]loadImageWithURL:url target:nil success:nil failure:nil];

           // cell3.mostProductimg.clipsToBounds=YES;

            cell3.mostPopularviewbtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            [cell3.mostPopularviewbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick3:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    // Configure the cell


    return cell3;
}
```

collection view cell code-

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MostPopularViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
            return nil;
        }

        if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
            return nil;
        }

        self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];




    }

    return self;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you want and what does it look like right now?

Comment: How to attach screenshot?

Comment: Edit your question and in the text view press "cntrl+g". It'll open a window to select an image from your system.

Comment: My guess is that it's because of the reuse. Don't add a subview like that, put the `UIImageView` (or it's inherited class `AsyncImageView`) already in your custom `UICollectionViewCell` (`MostPopularViewCell`). Or in prepareForReuse, remove the `AsyncImageView`.

Comment: @Larme I have done what you said but now Images are not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `[cell3.mostProductimg  addSubview:imageView];` give your image view a tag,and remove subview with the same tag from your custom cell. so you can replace `[cell3.mostProductimg  addSubview:imageView];` with

```
imageView.tag=123;
UIView *viewToRemove = [cell3.mostProductimg viewWithTag:123];
if(viewToRemove !=nil)
   [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
[cell3.mostProductimg  addSubview:imageView];
```

This should work.
The problem with your code is that you are reusing cells and adding imageView every time. You could add the imageView in the custom cell's xib and create an outlet to it. After that you could use the outlet to change its image rather than adding a new imageView on top of it.
Hope this helps.